# libxl: error: libxl_create.c:720:libxl__domain_make: domain creation fail: Permission denied

Tags: linux, debian, arm, xen, devuan

I'm trying to boot Linux 6.1.y as Xen dom0 on the Chromebook xe303c12, aka Snow and configure and start a very basic domU guest,following the Chuck's tutorial,located here :

https://github.com/mobile-virt/u-boot-chromebook-xe303c12/tree/chromebook/xen#starting-a-domu-guest

What I did has been to carefully follow his instructions,but I haven't found a solution to fix this problem,yet :

```
# sudo xl create devuan.cfg -c
    
Parsing config from devuan.cfg
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:720:libxl__domain_make: 
domain creation fail: Permission denied
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:1309:initiate_domain_create: nnot make domain: -3
```

This is my devuan.cfg file :

```
kernel = '/Dati/xen/kernels/zImage-6.1.59-stb-xen-cbe+'
memory = '512'
name = 'Devuan'
vcpus = '1'
disk = [ '/Dati/xen/devuan.img,,xvda,w' ]
extra = 'console=hvc0 root=/dev/xvda rw init=/sbin/init xen-fbfront.video=24,1024,768'
```

(I have tried also with root=/dev/xvda1 and root=/dev/xvda2,but leaving disk = [ '/Dati/xen/devuan.img,,xvda,w' ] and not xvda1 or 2)

I have no  idea about the reason(s) I always get that error,but I don't think it is caused by a wrong creation of the devuan.img file. Can someone point me in the right direction to understand what could be wrong ? I haven't found any useful information on the internet.

This is bootxen.scr file where I have configured dom0_mem=768 :

```
mmc dev 1
ext2load mmc 1:3 0x42000000 zImage-6.6.0-xen-iommu-dma-on-xen
ext2load mmc 1:3 0x51000000 xen-4.17-armhf-armmp-0x51004000.ub
ext2load mmc 1:3 0x5ffec000 exynos5250-snow.dtb
fdt addr 0x5ffec000
fdt resize 1024
fdt set /chosen \#address-cells <0x2>
fdt set /chosen \#size-cells <0x2>
fdt set /chosen xen,xen-bootargs "console=dtuart dtuart=serial0 dom0_mem=768M dom0_max_vcpus=2 bootscrub=0 vwfi=native sched=null"
fdt mknod /chosen dom0
fdt set /chosen/dom0 compatible  "xen,linux-zimage" "xen,multiboot-module" "multiboot,module"
fdt set /chosen/dom0 reg <0x0 0x42000000 0x0 0x87C200 >
fdt set /chosen xen,dom0-bootargs "console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk1p4 rw rootwait clk_ignore_unused --no-log"
bootm 0x51000000 - 0x5ffec000
```

and I've rebooted the Chromebook using this command :

```
SMDK5250 # mmc dev 1
SMDK5250 # ext2load mmc 1:3 0x50000000 bootxen.scr; source 0x50000000
```

This is the memory available on the machine after having booted the machine ready for xen :

```
# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            741         329         108           7         332         412
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Thanks in advance for any support.